# Pagination links get_next_posts_link() is not working

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to add a page navigator to my wordpress site. I have go through the wordpress website and copied it exactly into my code, but for some reason it is not working.

here is my code, am I making a syntax error? any help would be appreciated

```
       <?php 
       $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
       $args = array (
         'post_type' => 'post',
         'category_name' => get_the_title(),
         'posts_per_page' => 5,
         'paged' => $paged,
       );
       $query = new WP_Query($args);
       if ( have_posts() ) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
       ?>
       <hr />
       <?php endwhile; ?>
      </div>
        
        
        <div class="pagination flex-row">
          <a href="<?php get_next_posts_link('older posts'); ?>"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> 
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="page-numbers">1</a>
          <a href="#" class="page-numbers">2</a>
          <a href="#" class="page-numbers">3</a>
          <a href="<?php get_previous_posts_link('older posts'); ?>"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"> 
          </i></a>
          <h1> <?php get_previous_posts_link('older posts'); ?>
          <?php get_next_posts_link('older posts'); ?>
        </h1>
        </div>
          <?php endif;  wp_reset_query();?>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get-functions return something instead of echoing it. Add `echo` before every function like

```
echo get_previous_posts_link('older posts');
```

and so on

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't. I think it may have something to do with the placement? Because when I tried echoing it into the <h1> I dont get any values

Comment: No need to paste it inside of anchor tag beacause function's output is anchor tag itself. Also I just mentioned category_name in query args should be category slug, but get_the_title returns the actual name of the category. Maybe it cannot find any posts and that's why there no any next/prev link. If you still need this functionality, try sanitize_title(get_the_title))

Comment: Thanks for your help I appreciate it. I used get_the_title so that it is responsive to the page that is being displayed. I was sure how to link the categories relatively because it is on a page template. However, I found the problem. I need to use get_the_next_posts_page_link()